# soap wsdl request - "Bad Request - Invalid Header"

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm testing posting to a web-service, and it's throwing a "Bad Request - Invalid Header" in my Java code.

Here's the soap action url:  http://www.webservicex.net/GetNAICSByIndustry

This is the XML I'm posting:

```
         String reqStr = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                            "<Body>" +
                                "<GetNAICSByIndustry xmlns=\"http://www.webservicex.net/\"> " +
                                    "<IndustryName>wef</IndustryName>" +
                                "</GetNAICSByIndustry>" +
                            "</Body>" +
                        "</Envelope>";
```

Here's the header...

```
        int len = reqStr.length();
        rc.setRequestProperty( "Connection:", "Keep-Alive" );
        rc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( len ) );
        rc.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type:", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" );
        rc.setRequestProperty( "Host:", "www.webservicex.net");
        rc.setRequestProperty( "SOAPAction:", "http://www.webservicex.net/GetNAICSByIndustry");
```

I used the chrome plug-in wizdler [which works in getting a proper response], and those are the headers when posting to it..

When I do a curl it will respond properly [request.xml is the same as reqStr]:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: \"http://www.webservicex.net/GetNAICSByIndustry\"" --data-binary @request.xml http://www.webservicex.net/GenericNAICS.asmx
```

Comment: You probably should not have quotes around your header value. -H "SOAPAction: http://www..." (notice the left out escaped double quotes).

Comment: I should have clarified, that CURL is working properly.  In the header response using wizdler it surrounds the SOAPAction value with double quotes.  And in the Java Code, I had specified it to use double quotes like so: rc.setRequestProperty( "SOAPAction:", "\"http://www.webservicex.net/GetNAICSByIndustry\""); to no avail.

Comment: Following this appeared to do the trick: http://technology.amis.nl/2011/06/29/how-to-call-a-call-a-webservice-directly-from-java-without-webservice-library/